Issue opening a looped MUI Controlled Accordions
I have two lists of accordions. I want both accordion sets to be in sync with each other. For example, if I open accordion 1 in the left, I want accordion 1 in the right to be open and vice versa. I am already maintaining the state to keep the accordions open by default Please help me on what I am doing wrong.
This is my code:
    import * as React from 'react';
    import Accordion from '@mui/material/Accordion';
    import AccordionDetails from '@mui/material/AccordionDetails';
    import AccordionSummary from '@mui/material/AccordionSummary';
    import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
    import ExpandMoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';

    export default function ControlledAccordions() {
      const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState<Record<string, boolean>>({});

      const arr = [1, 2, 3];

      React.useEffect(() => {
        setExpanded(
          arr.reduce((a, c) => {
            a[`panel${c}`] = true;
            return a;
          }, {} as Record<string, boolean>)
        );
      }, []);

      const handleChange =
        (panel: string) => (event: React.SyntheticEvent, isExpanded: boolean) => {
          setExpanded({
            ...expanded,
            [panel]: isExpanded,
          });
        };

      console.log('expanded', expanded);

      return (
        <div
          style={{
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'row',
          }}
        >
          <div>
            {arr.map((i) => (
              <Accordion
                expanded={expanded[`panel${i}`]}
                onChange={handleChange(`panel${i}`)}
              >
                <AccordionSummary
                  expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                  aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
                  id={`leftpanel${i}bh-header`}
                >
                  <Typography sx={{ width: '33%', flexShrink: 0 }}>
                    General settings
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography sx={{ color: 'text.secondary' }}>
                    I am an accordion
                  </Typography>
                </AccordionSummary>
                <AccordionDetails>
                  <Typography>
                    Nulla facilisi. Phasellus sollicitudin nulla et quam mattis
                    feugiat. Aliquam eget maximus est, id dignissim quam.
                  </Typography>
                </AccordionDetails>
              </Accordion>
            ))}
          </div>
          <div>
            {arr.map((i) => (
              <Accordion
                expanded={expanded[`panel${i}`]}
                onChange={handleChange(`panel${i}`)}
              >
                <AccordionSummary
                  expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                  aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
                  id={`rightpanel${i}bh-header`}
                >
                  <Typography sx={{ width: '33%', flexShrink: 0 }}>
                    General settings
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography sx={{ color: 'text.secondary' }}>
                    I am an accordion
                  </Typography>
                </AccordionSummary>
                <AccordionDetails>
                  <Typography>
                    Nulla facilisi. Phasellus sollicitudin nulla et quam mattis
                    feugiat. Aliquam eget maximus est, id dignissim quam.
                  </Typography>
                </AccordionDetails>
              </Accordion>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }

My Stackblitz URL: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7qktzd?file=Demo.tsx
Please advice.

when I render this component I get a console error:  "MUI: A component is changing the uncontrolled expanded state of Accordion to be controlled.
Elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa)". And the react dev website says to create a parent element if you want to coordinate components like the accordion: https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components#controlled-and-uncontrolled-components. Try giving this a go!

have you ever opened the console? Didn't you see any error there?

I think this can be fixed if you remove the first useEffect since you are just trying to set the initial state of the accordions as opened? And arr doesn't change after that anyways.
Here's how I would go about it:

remove the first useEffect and use arr to set the initial state of expanded:

// don't need this
// React.useEffect(() => {
//        setExpanded(
//          arr.reduce((a, c) => {
//            a[`panel${c}`] = true;
//            return a;
//          }, {} as Record<string, boolean>)
//        );
//      }, []);


const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState<Record<string, boolean>>(
   // same reduce function from useEffect above
    arr.reduce((a, c) => {
      a[`panel${c}`] = true;
      return a;
    }, {} as Record<string, boolean>)
  );


update Accordion expanded attribute to whatever is in expanded state, which will be guaranteed to have a value by the time it gets here:

<Accordion
            key={i}
            expanded={expanded[`panel${i}`]}
            onChange={handleChange(`panel${i}`)}
          >

And all together:
import * as React from 'react';
import Accordion from '@mui/material/Accordion';
import AccordionDetails from '@mui/material/AccordionDetails';
import AccordionSummary from '@mui/material/AccordionSummary';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';

export default function ControlledAccordions() {
  const arr = [1, 2, 3];

  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState<Record<string, boolean>>(
    arr.reduce((a, c) => {
      a[`panel${c}`] = true;
      return a;
    }, {} as Record<string, boolean>)
  );
  const handleChange =
    (panel: string) => (event: React.SyntheticEvent, isExpanded: boolean) => {
      setExpanded({
        ...expanded,
        [panel]: isExpanded,
      });
    };

  console.log('expanded', expanded);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
      }}
    >
      <div>
        {arr.map((i) => (
          <Accordion
            key={i} 
            expanded={expanded[`panel${i}`]} // removed || true here
            onChange={handleChange(`panel${i}`)}
          >
            <AccordionSummary
              expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
              aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
              id={`panel${i}bh-header`}
            >
              <Typography sx={{ width: '33%', flexShrink: 0 }}>
                General settings
              </Typography>
              <Typography sx={{ color: 'text.secondary' }}>
                I am an accordion
              </Typography>
            </AccordionSummary>
            <AccordionDetails>
              <Typography>
                Nulla facilisi. Phasellus sollicitudin nulla et quam mattis
                feugiat. Aliquam eget maximus est, id dignissim quam.
              </Typography>
            </AccordionDetails>
          </Accordion>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>
        {arr.map((i) => (
          <Accordion
            key={i}
            expanded={expanded[`panel${i}`]}
            onChange={handleChange(`panel${i}`)}
          >
            <AccordionSummary
              expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
              aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
              id={`panel${i}bh-header`}
            >
              <Typography sx={{ width: '33%', flexShrink: 0 }}>
                General settings
              </Typography>
              <Typography sx={{ color: 'text.secondary' }}>
                I am an accordion
              </Typography>
            </AccordionSummary>
            <AccordionDetails>
              <Typography>
                Nulla facilisi. Phasellus sollicitudin nulla et quam mattis
                feugiat. Aliquam eget maximus est, id dignissim quam.
              </Typography>
            </AccordionDetails>
          </Accordion>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


But you should still consider moving things to a parent component like the react docs says here: https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components#controlled-and-uncontrolled-components

Thanks. The reason I set the arr is because I will be getting the data through an async call. I was able to fix it by checking if its empty and render the accordion only if the state value is not empty.

I was able to fix it by checking if its empty and render the accordion only if the state value is not empty.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7qktzd-imzy6p?file=Demo.tsx
